# UITableView has 'dead' areas

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a dialog as below. It uses its parent controller. It has dead zones where if you touch cells you cannot scroll, select, or activate the 'accessory' button. The table is by itself in a UIView that is placed below the upper parts which are also in their own UIView. Specifically in the screen below, only the three middle cells are selectable or can be used for scrolling.  Here those are 'Clara J', 'Circe', and 'Red Sky'.  The ones above and below it do nothing and will not scroll the table.  Reproduced on iPhone and iPad.

Any ideas why these areas don't respond?

Xcode 12.4 and Swift 5. Reproduced on iOS 12.5.1 and 14.4

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Most likely the parent view is clipping the user interaction without clipping the rendering.

Comment: Try using the view debugging feature in Xcode. It will capture the view hierarchy and let you examine it graphically, including the ordering of views.As LGP says, you may have a problem with your parent view clipping the subview. In that case you might need to make the parent view(s) big enough to fully enclose the child view.

Comment: LGP had it.  It was not obvious that a containing view could clip interaction, but not visibility. Thanks.  Also, Duncan C had a good idea, but it did not work.  The viewer was just a blank frame, and when I tried selecting the main thread it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

It was a containing view. A containing view can clip interactions (touches, etc) but not clip visibility.  Stretching the containing UIView to the size of the UITableView inside it solved the problem.